# LinkedIn Marketing API ignores pagination and return all elements

Tags: pagination, linkedin-api

I am using the marketing API
I have an issue with the pagination, it seems like it ignores the start and count.
I am using the start and count query parameters and no matter what number I put in the count, I get a response with all the results
I followed this document for pagination:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/pagination

I use this endpoint:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2

my parameters include:
start=0&count=10&q=statistics&timeGranularity=MONTHLY ....

in the response, I received 821 elements without any pagination. instead of 10 per page.

if I use the logic in the docs the values for start and count will not affect the results or the query

what am I doing wrong?
I don't want to use it without pagination and find out later that I missed records.

Thanks,
Roiy

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, as a "workaround" instead of getting data by `account`, now I'm doing it by `campaign` which reduces considerably the total results, maybe this could work for you as well in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is a good idea and what I did in the meantime
now I don't have too many records but in the future, this can cause an issue

Answer (score 0):

I have used pagination to retrieve the posts of the organization, and its working for me
my api call is

api_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A123456&sharesPerOwner=1000&count=100&start=0"

one thing importantly i noticed is this does not requires restli2.0 version(dont pass this in header)